# Inconsistent heading numbering in LibreOffice writer

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

The document I'm working on has developed a strange numbering of the headings:

From the table contents (that reflects the sorry state of the headings):

```
1. 
2. 
3. 
3.1. 
3.1.1. 
3.1.1.1.
3.1.2. 
3.1.2.1. 
3.1.2.2. 
3.1.2.3. 
3.1.3. 
3.1.4. 
1.1.1.1 # 1st reset of Heading4 numbering (with extra indent?) 
3.1.5. 
1.1.1.1 # Also restarts from 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
3.2. 
3.2.1. 
1.1.1.3 # Doens't restart from 1.1.1.1
1.1.2   # Now for heading3, but where is 1.1.1?
1.1.2.1
1.1.3
```

As far as I can tell, the style for Heading 4 has the Outline Level and Numbering Style disabled and everything looks fine in `Tools>Outline numbering`.

On the first 1.1.1.1 Heading4, if I right-click and select "Continue previous numbering", the heading morphs into to a bullet list item. This can have something to do with mixed numbering styles, but I have don't see any selected in the "Styles and Formatting/List Styles" sidebar.

Bonus points: why is there a final dot on some heading numbers and not on others?

The document is initially a MS-Word document (gutted from all its contents except header/footer, and first two header pages, that was later clipboard-copied into an empty LO documents in the hope that this would shake out all the MS-Word clutter.

Using LO 5.3.7.2 on Linux

Comment: The numbering in the word doc is correct?  Also, did you try either (or both) of Saving As... in Word to LO format, or opening the Word doc (File/Open) straight up in LO?  In my experience, conversion seems to work pretty well.  Also, also if you really want to clean out Word clutter, filter the doc through notepad++ or another text editor on the way to LO.

Comment: No access to Word. Initially opened a Word document (.docx) in LO.

Comment: Thanks for the very good report. Same problem here with 5.2.7.2, no solution :-(

Comment: Still a problem in LO 6.2.8.2. The (only) answer below indicates a solution for a single occurence, but when the inconsistencies become systematic, it is tedious. Unfortunately I did not find a promising answer in the LO/OOo forums.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully rectified the numbering by 
Right click on section heading -> Bullets and numbering -> Continue previous numbering.